# React router rendering multiple components

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

In my react app I'm using `react router` for routing and, in my app I don't want to render navbar for some routes like `login page, create account page, etc.`. Also when user enters a non-existing route it should render a 404 page.

How Can I do that? What kind of arrangement I have to do in order to render pages like this. With current setup it is rendering 404 page along with `login and register pages`.

How do I solve this problem?

```html
 {/* Routes Without Nav */}
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/login">
          <Login notify={setResMessage} />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/user/create">
          <CreateAc notify={setResMessage} />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/mobile/search">
          <MobileSearchPage notify={setResMessage} />
        </Route>
        <Navbar notify={setResMessage} />
      </Switch>

      <Switch>
        {/* Routes With Nav */}
        <Route exact path="/">
          <Home notify={setResMessage} />
          <Footer />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/cart">
          <Cart />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/product/:productID">
          <ProductDetails notify={setResMessage} />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/search/:product">
          <SearchPage notify={setResMessage} />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/payment-success">
          <PaymentSuccess />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/recommended">
          <Recommendations />
        </Route>
        {/* ----------------Not So IMP Routes---------------- */}
        <Route exact path="/create-product" component={AddProduct} />
        <Route component={PageNotFound} />
      </Switch>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For Navbar, you could have a condition to prevent it from showing within the component itself:**

Something like this:

```
function Nav() {
  const location = useLocation();
  if (location.pathname !== "/page2") return <h3>NAV BAR</h3>;
  return null;
}
```

And for the 404 page, you place it at the end of the Switch, if there is no matching route, then render 404:

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/">
    <Home />
  </Route>
  <Route path="/page1">
    <Page1 />
  </Route>
  <Route path="/page2">
    <Page2 />
  </Route>
  <Route path="*">
    <Page404 />
  </Route>
</Switch>;
```

Live Example:

[image: Edit React Router - 404 - Navbar condition]

Answer (score 1):

the best practice for this is to make  a Layout component and use that when ever you want to show the navbar and other related stuff around layout . it should be like this

```js
function Layout(props) {
  const { children } = props ;  
  return (
    <div> 
      <Navbar/> 
       {children}
    </div>
  ) 
}

function ComponentsWithLayout() { 
  return ( 
    <Layout> 
      {/* component code comes here */}
   </Layout> 
  ) 
}
```